# How to use arm-none-eabi with multiple files?

Tags: gcc, arm, eabi

I'm trying to make a modified version of the FlySky FS-i6 firmware. After a bit of searching, I found someone who decompiled the source code [here](https://github.com/qba667/FlySkyI6).

I'm trying to compile using arm-none-eabi, which I already have installed from the Arduino IDE.

Here's a batch file I made to compile the files, which are just a bunch of .c and .h files under several directories, but I have no clue what arguments I'm supposed to be giving the arm-none-eabi-gcc command...

```
@echo off

set EABI_PATH="%LocalAppData%\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\arm-none-eabi-gcc\4.8.3-2014q1\bin"

@RD /S /Q temp
mkdir temp

for /D %%d in (*) do (
    echo ---- Compiling Directory: %%d
    rem C Files:
    for %%f in (%%d/*.c) do (
        "%EABI_PATH%/arm-none-eabi-gcc" -c -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -g "%%d/%%f" -o "temp/%%~nf.o" -mthumb -g3
    )
    rem Header Files:
    rem for %%f in (%%d/*.h) do (
    rem "%EABI_PATH%/arm-none-eabi-gcc" -c -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -g "%%d/%%f" -o "temp/%%~nf.o" -mthumb -g3
    rem )
)
```

I've searched everywhere, but I can't find any tutorials or anything about how to use the tool. All I want to do is compile the files to a firmware.hex file, you'd think it would just be a simple one-liner...

Comment: heh heh, C compilation is never a "simple one-liner"

Comment: You "searched everywhere" and could not find documentation on the GNU C compiler? Ignore the "arm-non-eabi" stuff and look at how to compile using "gcc". You'll find it.

Comment: Thanks. I found the -I flag, which I think solved my problem, because now the errors I'm getting are more project-specific.